# Чтение переменных без плагинов в pom.xml

Tags: java, xml, maven

```
  <groupId>com.mycompany.app</groupId>
  <artifactId>my-app</artifactId>
  <packaging>jar</packaging>
  <version>1F.034673.434534-S</version>
  <name>my-app</name>
  <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>
```

Существует pom.xml где есть блок 1F.034673.434534-S, как сделать чтение версии из другого файла? Спасибо.

Comment: Из какого другого? Не из `pom.xml`?

Comment: напирмер из config.cfg именно <version>${some.thing}</version>

Comment: по-моему, никак, разве что написать свой плагин для этого.. переходите на gradle

Comment: щас только заказчику об этом скажу))